# Return array to a class

Tags: java, arrays, xml, multidimensional-array, return

I am trying to pass a xml file name to a function (`getAllXmlData`) and extract its data and store them in a multidimensional array and return the xml data via `xmlArray` to the first class. I have the following code:

```
public class Utils {

    static String[][] getAllXmlData(String strIn1) {
        File file = new File(strIn1);
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(file);
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
            System.out.println("Total of elements : " + nodes.getLength());
            String xmlArray[][] = new String[nodes.getLength()][12];
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                NodeList recordID = element.getElementsByTagName("RecordID");
                Element line = (Element) recordID.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][1] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                xmlArray[i][2] = line.getAttribute("id");

                NodeList lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("LastName");
                line = (Element) lastName.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][3] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                NodeList firstName = element.getElementsByTagName("FirstName");
                line = (Element) firstName.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][4] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("Title");
                line = (Element) title.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][5] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                NodeList hobby = element.getElementsByTagName("Hobby");
                line = (Element) hobby.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][6] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                NodeList phone1 = element.getElementsByTagName("CellPhone");
                line = (Element) phone1.item(0);
                xmlArray[i][7] = line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return xmlArray;
    }
}
```

but getting the following error:

```
Utils.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
return xmlArray;
symbol: vailable xmlArray
location: class Utils
```

I appriciate any help. Also, if there is more efficent and dynamic way to storing the xml data in the array without having to do it element by elemnt.
Thx

Comment: the declaration is inside the try catch block. anything outside that scope cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

Move xmlArray out of the try/catch:

```
public class Utils {         
         static String[][] getAllXmlData(String strIn1) {    
                        File file = new File(strIn1);
                        String xmlArray[][] = null;
                        try {
                                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                                Document doc = builder.parse(file);
                                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
                                System.out.println("Total of elements : " + nodes.getLength());
                                xmlArray = new String[nodes.getLength()][12];     
                                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                                        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                                        NodeList recordID = element.getElementsByTagName("RecordID");
                                        Element line = (Element) recordID.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][1]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                                        xmlArray[i][2]=line.getAttribute("id");

                                        NodeList lastName = element.getElementsByTagName("LastName");
                                        line = (Element) lastName.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][3]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                                        NodeList firstName = element.getElementsByTagName("FirstName");
                                        line = (Element) firstName.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][4]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                                        NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("Title");
                                        line = (Element) title.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][5]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                                        NodeList hobby = element.getElementsByTagName("Hobby");
                                        line = (Element) hobby.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][6]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();

                                        NodeList phone1 = element.getElementsByTagName("CellPhone");
                                        line = (Element) phone1.item(0);
                                        xmlArray[i][7]=line.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                             }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                        }      
                        return xmlArray;
         }
}
```

Comment: OK. Thx. But than how I can get the exact size of the array?

Comment: You're just declaring the array outside the scope of the try/block so that you can access it after. You're still instantiating it where you currently have it.